# Laravel Http client redirects to login page even after using cookies in subsequent requests - ChatGPT suggested approach already tried

Tags: laravel, authentication, http, cookies

I'm using Laravel Http client to scrape data from a website but to access the data I need to authenticate first. I was able to successfully authenticate using the code below:

```
$authResponse = Http::asForm()->post('https://www.example.com/login.php', [
    'email' => 'sample@mail.com',
    'password' => '12345678',
]);
```

Next, I retrieved the cookies from the response using `$authResponse->cookies()`, and attempted to use them with headers in another request to get user details, but it just redirected me back to the login page:

```
$userDetailsResponse = Http::withHeaders([
    'Cookie' => $authResponse->cookies(),
])->get('https://www.example.com/profile.php');
```

However, I was able to accomplish this with cURL using this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554993/curl-login-with-existing-accounts), but I'm interested in using the Laravel HTTP client instead. I know that for APIs we typically use a Bearer token with each authenticated request, but in this case, I'd like to use cookies.

I even asked about this from the ChatGPT, and it suggested the same approach I used. So, I'm hoping to get some fresh insights or guidance on how to accomplish this with the Laravel HTTP client.

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So I asked the same question at [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-http-client-redirects-to-login-page-even-after-using-cookies-in-subsequent-requests-chatgpt-suggested-approach-already-tried) and with their AI help, I was able to fix this.

So Laracast AI was providing the below answer to me.

> It's possible that the cookies are not being properly formatted when
> passed in the headers. Try converting the cookies array to a string
> using the `http_build_query` function before passing it in the headers.
> Here's an example:

```
$cookies = http_build_query($authResponse->cookies());
$userDetailsResponse = Http::withHeaders([
         'Cookie' => $cookies, ])->get('https://www.example.com/profile.php');
```

> If that doesn't work,
> you can try manually setting the cookies in the client's cookie jar
> using the `withCookie` method. Here's an example:

```
 $client = Http::withHeaders([
     'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110
 Safari/537.36', ])->withOptions([
     'cookies' => true, ]);
 
 $authResponse =
 $client->asForm()->post('https://www.example.com/login.php', [
     'email' => 'sample@mail.com',
     'password' => '12345678', ]);
 
 $userDetailsResponse =
 $client->withCookie($authResponse->cookies())-get('https://www.example.com/profile.php');
```

> This sets the cookies option to true when creating the client, which
> enables the cookie jar. Then, the `withCookie` method is used to
> manually set the cookies from the authentication response.

However there we some issues with Laracast AI answer.Let me go through each error I faced.

First error :

> `"cookies must be an instance of GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJarInterface."`

To fix first error I updated my code below:

```
$cookieJar = new CookieJar();
$client = Http::withHeaders([
    'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36',
])->withOptions([
    'cookies' => $cookieJar,
]);
```

Then I received the error

> `"Method Illuminate\Http\Client\PendingRequest::withCookie does not exist."`

To fix it, I updated my code as below:

```
$cookies = $authResponse->cookies();
foreach ($cookies as $cookie) {
    $cookieJar->setCookie($cookie);
}

$userDetailsResponse = $client->withOptions([
    'cookies' => $cookieJar,
])->get('https://www.example.com/profile.php');
```

After making these changes, everything started to work as required. Thanks again to @LaryAI.

**Here is the full working code:**

```
use GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar;

$cookieJar = new CookieJar();

$client = Http::withHeaders([
    'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36',
])->withOptions([
    'cookies' => $cookieJar,
]);

$authResponse = $client->asForm()->post('https://www.example.com/login.php', [
    'email' => 'sample@mail.com',
    'password' => '12345678',
]);

// Get the cookies as an array and add them to the cookie jar manually
$cookies = $authResponse->cookies();
foreach ($cookies as $cookie) {
    $cookieJar->setCookie($cookie);
}

$userDetailsResponse = $client->withOptions([
    'cookies' => $cookieJar,
])->get('https://www.example.com/profile.php');
```